# How can i shorten the link to my supplementary material inside the paper?

Tags: supporting-information

I have some supplementary materials for my paper, including graphs and videos, which are saved on Figshare. I have included a URL link to these materials in my paper. One reviewer has requested that I make the URL shorter and more easily accessible. I need a suggestion on how to do this. Should I use a URL shortener service or put the Figshare link in the references?

Answer (score 3):

I think putting the Figshare link in the references would be better than using a URL shortener service like bitly.

There is also https://shortdoi.org/, which would work if you have a DOI from Figshare. This service might be more permanent than other URL shortener services. But you might need to make changes to the supplementary materials before the paper is published, so you should check whether this will be possible. For example read this: https://figshare.com/blog/figshare_new_features_Get_DOI_or_private_sharing_link/135

Or you could explain the issues to the reviewer and tell them you will make a shorter link when the paper is accepted for publication (in this journal or a different journal).

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to create a GitHub repository, and link to it in your paper. It's commonplace to add links to GitHub repositories in computer science.